# Changing the root element of an xml document (svg)

Tags: xml, qt, parsing, svg

I need to work with svg objects using a `QGraphicsSvgItem` sublcass.

I am learning about svg - and what I have noticed is, the svg shows fine if its root element is `<svg ..>`

Yet, playing with w3schools samples, I noticed all their examples embedded in html, and it is possible that my code will have to process both kinds (simple svg, as well as html containing svg).

So, the solution as I see it is, extract the svg element (with all its kids) and replace the root element with it.

In my mind the code is clear:

```
QDomDocument _svgXML;

void setContentFromFile(QString filename)
{
    QFile file(filename);
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString data = in.readAll();
    file.close();
    _svgXML.setContent(svgContent);

    checkRoot();
}

void checkRoot()
{
    QDomElement rootElem = _svgXML.documentElement();
    recursivelyCheckRoot(rootElem);
    qDebug(qPrintable(QString("root ") + rootElem.nodeName()));
    // or
    qDebug(_svgXML.toByteArray());
}
void recursivelyCheckRoot(QDomElement& rootElem)
{
    if(rootElem.nodeName() == "svg")
        return;

    QDomNode n = rootElem.firstChild();
    while(!n.isNull())
    {
      if(n.isElement())
      {
          QDomElement e = n.toElement();
          if(e.nodeName() == "svg") 
          {
            rootElem = e; return; 
          }
          recursivelyCheckRoot(e);
      }
      n = n.nextSibling();
    }    
}
```

The only problem is that it doesn't work. I see no change.

Please help me extract the svg element and make it root... discarding all else.

Sample source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <svg width="400" height="150">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" y1="0%" x1="0%" y2="0%" x2="100%">
     <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
     <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <ellipse fill="url(#grad1)" cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55"/>
   <text x="150" y="86" fill="green" font-family="Verdana" font-size="45">SVG</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.

</svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Desired result:

```
<svg width="400" height="150">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad1" y1="0%" x1="0%" y2="0%" x2="100%">
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <ellipse fill="url(#grad1)" cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55"/>
 <text x="150" y="86" fill="green" font-family="Verdana" font-size="45">SVG</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.

</svg>
```

(the `!DOCTYPE` or any other declarations could stay)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Once an html document, always an html document I think.

Comment: @RobertLongson  LOL :)))) ..... Yet it should be possible to extract a node with all its children from the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I understood - based on Robert Longson's comment "Once an html document, always an html document" ... I realized that I cannot modify an existing document, I had to make a new one.

```
void recursivelyCheckRoot(QDomElement rootElem)
{
    if(rootElem.nodeName() == "svg")
        return;

    QDomNode n = rootElem.firstChild();
    while(!n.isNull())
    {
      if(n.isElement())
      {
          QDomElement e = n.toElement();
          if(e.nodeName() == "svg") 
          {
              QString str;
              QTextStream stream(&str);
              e.save(stream, QDomNode::DocumentNode);
              _svgXML.setContent(str);
              return;
          }
          recursivelyCheckRoot(e);
      }
      n = n.nextSibling();
    }    
}
```